# jquery addClass not working on tablecell

Tags: jquery, addclass, tablecell

I need some help with this

I am trying to do this

```
if(perc>0){
alert('change backgroundcolor and textcolor');
$('#stocktable tr td:last').addClass('stockhigher');
```

}

but It does not work on a tablecell

I also try'd to set the selector like this

```
$('#stocktable tr td:eq(2)).addClass...
$('#stocktable tr td.percentage').addClass...
```

nothing!

it does work on the table itself or a tablerow like

```
$('#stocktable tr')
```

am I missing something here?

thanks, Richard

Comment: Can you provide the HTML markup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three things spring to mind:

1. You're using the `:last` pseudo-element. That will match at most one element total, in this case the very last table cell in "stocktable". Do you perhaps mean `:last-child` instead?
2. You're using `:eq(2)` which will match the *third* element in the entire set only. Do you perhaps mean `:nth-child(2)`?
3. `$("#stocktable tr td.eq(2)).addClass...` is missing and end quote; and
4. There is nothing wrong with what you're doing. What precisely isn't working? Perhaps it's not formatting that can be applied to a table cell.

To further explain (1) imagine you have a table with 3 rows of 4 cells with an id of "mytable". This code:

```
$("#mytable td:eq(2)").css("background", "yellow");
```

will colour the *third* element of the first row (`:eq()` is zero-based) whereas:

```
$("#mytable td:nth-child(2)").css("background", "yellow");
```

will colour the *second* cell in *each* row.

```
$("#mytable td:last").css("background", "yellow");
```

will colour the very last cell in the very last row but:

```
$("#mytable td:last-child").css("background", "yellow");
```

will colour the last cell in *each* row.

Comment: thank you, now I wished you wherent so fast.
I was being stupid, the problem was that I replaced all the td's
two lines after the evaluation, sorry

Comment: if it's possible to delete the post then please do.